# Delphi 7 turn off creation of DDP files

Tags: delphi

How do you turn off the feature or stop the creation of all the .ddp files for your Delphi 7 forms?  I read something about removing the designdgm60.bpl, but is that the only way? It seems that there was another way I can't remember any longer.

Update: I tried renaming the designdgm70.bpl and that just creates a ton of program errors.
Also, I'm using Delphi 7.2 on one computer and there is no design tab I can see unless its covered by something in CnWizards.  7.2 definitely creates the ddp files though.

Answer (score 10):

DDP files are for Delphi diagrams (DDP stands for [Delphi Diagram Portfolio](http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=68167)) in Delphi 6-7. Delphi 5 used the DTI extension for this.

DDP files can have meaningful information. They don't get compiled into .DCU/.EXE./... as they are for documentation purposes only.

Did you create diagrams of components on your form/datamodule? I used to do that (to explain structure to co-workers) so I was actually really happy with the DDP files.

Before deleting them, inspect them to see if they contain documentation you want to keep.

You can safely delete them if they are 51 bytes long and the [TDUMP](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/TDUMP.EXE,_the_File_Dumping_Utility) of it looks like this:

```
000000: 07 18 44 45 4C 50 48 49  2E 44 49 41 47 52 41 4D ..DELPHI.DIAGRAM
000010: 2E 50 4F 52 54 46 4F 4C  49 4F 0F 00 00 E0 40 02 .PORTFOLIO....@.
000020: 01 09 06 09 55 6E 74 69  74 6C 65 64 31 06 00 02 ....Untitled1...
000030: 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
```

Comment: Since this does not address the question, it should be a comment.

Comment: I made the purpose of my answer more clear as I don't think these files have been auto generated and just deleting them might lose valuable documentation information.

Comment: They get created empty when you click on the design tab in the editor. That's the likely scenario.

Comment: That's a good one. I never did that without purpose, so never noticed this behaviour. Anyway: I think the warning is proper. Extended it a bit to make it clearer.

Comment: For reference, I"m not even clicking the design tab.  They are just being created.

Comment: @ChrisValentine now that is odd. Do you have auto desktop saving enabled? I know that setting had some issues in the pre-Galileo era.

Comment: Where is this setting? I did not see it

Comment: @ChrisValentine it is somewhere under Tools -> Options. I don't have a VM with Delphi 7 readily available right now, so I need to find the exact spot.

Comment: Found it: Tools -> Environment Options -> Preferences -> Autosave options -> Project Desktop.
See around 08:39 in this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0miOwBIYAms

Comment: Oh yes I think I have that checked.  Didn't know that was the same feature.

Comment: From memory, that feature also remembers which tabs you have open. If those include diagram tabs, then empty DDP files will be regenerated every time you open that project.

Answer (score 6):

I suppose that it's impossible to turn off .ddp creation in IDE by built-in methods, but [DDevExtensions](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/ddevextensions/) tool includes this option (File Cleaner)

Answer (score 2):

You can install [DDevExtensions](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/ddevextensions/) which is free.

There is an option which you can check that automatically deletes `.ddp` files.

[image]